# Hiding redudant link in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I want to hide link

```
@if(Route::has('dashboard.index'))
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{{ route('dashboard.index') }}">{{__('My Admin')}}</a>
</li>
@endif
```

And if I logged out and in web.php ,i hide route with middlewares (e.g authsanctum and verified):

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get(['DashContro::class','index])->name('dashboard.index');
```

.. but the Route::has() is still 'true'
What to use instead of route has for hiding links while logged out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally load HTML in blade based on login with the code below. The function [`Auth::check`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#determining-if-the-current-user-is-authenticated) returns true if the user is authenticated.

```
@if(Auth::check())
    // only show this if someone is logged in.
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

`Route::has` checks if the route **exists**, not if it's **accessible** to the user.

Instead, you should use Blade's `@auth` and `@guest` directives to show different things for logged-in or logged-out users.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#authentication-directives

```
@auth
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

Comment: Good. It looks like laravel has no such univesal possibility. I search such like @routeaccessible('route.name.index') ... @endrouteaccessible or something like.